# Using a variable in a heredoc

Tags: ruby

How can I use a Ruby variable in a heredoc? For instance:

```
<<XML
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?><data password="topsecret"></data>
XML
```

How can I set the password with a Ruby variable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it with `#{password}`, like

```
<<XML
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?><data password="#{password}"></data>
XML
```

Comment: You can omit curly brackets if it is instance or class variable (`#@a` or `#@@a`).

Answer (score 3):

Beside the version with `#{}` :

```
var = 'xxx'
v1 = <<XML
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?><data password="#{var}"></data>
XML
```

You can use `%`:

```
var = 'xxx'
#Version with format (%)
v2 = <<XML % var
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?><data password="%s"></data>
XML
```

This second version can also be used together with a heredoc in ':

```
var = 'xxx'
v3 = <<'XML' % var
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?><data password="%s"></data>
XML
```

This version can be useful if you don't wan't to mask each `\`.