# Github Api call from rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to give a call to github API i.e GET /users/:username/repos.Using HTTParty gem in rails if I do

```
def details
response = HTTParty.get('https://api.github.com/users/john/repos')
end
```

I get the expected result.
But if i do

```
def details(username)
response = HTTParty.get('https://api.github.com/users/#{username}/repos')
end
```

Getting InvalidUri error.
Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 2):

You are using single quotes in the string within your `get` request.

Single-quoted strings do not support variable interpolation. You need to use double quotes like so:

```
response = HTTParty.get("https://api.github.com/users/#{username}/repos")
```

Alternatively, don't use interpolation:

```
response = HTTParty.get('https://api.github.com/users/' + username + '/repos')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because string interpolation #{} will not work inside single quotes.
Try making a request with double quotes as:

```
def details(username)
  response = HTTParty.get("https://api.github.com/users/#{username}/repos")
end
```

String interpolation #{} only works with double quotes.

Comment: "String interpolation only works with double quotes." - incorrect. It works in many other string syntax variants. Just not in the single quotes.

Comment: "this link says that string interpolation will not work with double quotes" -
 That link does not say that. Quite the contrary, in fact.

Comment: Yes @SergioTulentsev, you are correct, i just typed wrongly. The **[link](http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/bonus/string_interpolation.html)** does not say that, rather it says like string interpolation only works with double quotes.

Comment: Yeah well, that article is factually wrong. Counter-example: `%W(user#{1 + 2}) # => ["user3"]`. Or [heredocs](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21810066/125816).